# App to post on Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, cron, access-token

I have an app that allows users to manage their Facebook Pages. I have done a section on my app where users can put posts on a queue and program them to be sent on the future. For example, a page administrator is going on vacation and prepares some posts to be sent while away.

This is done with a cron task that sends the posts when the scheduled time comes. The problem is that to write on a Page I need a Page Access Token and I can't get that with a App Access Token (or can't find how to do that).

Being a cron task there is no user interaction at all so I can't get neither an User Access Token nor a Page Access Token. The user has previously authorized a Facebook App with manage_pages and publish_stream permissions.

I've tried everything to exchange an App Access Token for a Page Access Token without success.

After struggling my mind and reading (almost) all the documentation on Facebook I came with an idea: maybe I could get the users Access Token when they prepare a post to be sent on the future and save it. The problem here is what would happen if the token expires or is invalidated.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do need `offline_access` which is deprecated which is now being replaced by Extended Expiry time Access Tokens.

Read : https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

You can just use the sample codes given on the documentation, and get an extended access token which you can then save to a database to be retrieved when the cron hits the time to fire the post.

Sample : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/